# SQL Query for topselling products

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to fetch all products (limit 5) which are topsellers (total sales) of the last 7 days.

My current Database Schema basically looks like this:

```
- products
 - id
 - name
 - price

- orders
 - id
 - purchased_at

- orders_products
 - id
 - products_id
 - orders_id
 - quantity
 - paid_price
```

I'm looking for the mysql syntax.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where is the order date?

Comment: @BrianWebster looks like `orders.purchased_at`

Comment: Wait, do you want the greatest quantity sold or the greatest monetary value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a relatively simple sequence of `INNER JOIN`s with an aggregate `SUM()` of the `quantity` multiplied by `paid_price`:

```
SELECT
  p.name,
  /* aggregate SUM() of orders_products qty * price */
  SUM(op.quantity * op.paid_price) AS total_sale_price
FROM
  products
  /* Join through orders_products (which gives the quantity) */
  INNER JOIN orders_products op ON p.id = op.products_id
  /* ...to orders (which provides the date) */
  INNER JOIN orders o ON op.orders_id = o.id
/* The last week... */
WHERE o.purchased_at >= (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 7 DAY)
GROUP BY p.name
/* In descending order of quantity, only the top 5 */
ORDER BY total_paid_price DESC LIMIT 5
```

I recommend spending some time reviewing [aggregate functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html).

Comment: thanks for your quick reply! i'm looking for the quantity * paid_price sum so its the monetary value hm is this possible?

Comment: @Oliver Updated above - just need to do the multiplication inside the `SUM()` aggregate.